# How can i get a Remote Mirror gitlab in Graphiql

Tags: gitlab, graphiql

Is there any way to list the mirrored gitlab repositories using Graphiql ? I'm listing the projects name and url and I need to include the mirrors in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [GitLab API documentation for remote mirrors](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/remote_mirrors.html).